# jQuery getScript and Google Maps API Error message

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I got a problem with loading the google maps api.

I got my own object with a function that initializes the map, and the google maps api gets loaded via jquery.getscript. but i always get an error message in the callback function:

```
var MyGMap = {
    GMapScriptURL: "http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&async=2&key=",
    Map: null,
    Geocoder: null,
    InitiazlizeMaps: function () {
        if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
            this.Map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
            this.Map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 13);
            this.Geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
        }
    }
}

$(function(){
    var CurrentKey = "MY_KEY";

    $.getScript(MyGMap.GMapScriptURL + CurrentKey, function () {
        MyGMap.InitiazlizeMaps();
        // throws GMap2 is undefined

    });
});
```

whats wrong? why is this not running?

Comment: what is th error message you get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got `async=2` in the script URL line which means load the mapping core asynchronously too - you need to wait for it to complete that before you can call InitializeMaps. You can either try dropping the `async=2` from the URL, or using Google Map's async and callback instead of the getScript callback function, e.g.

```
$.getScript(MyGMap.GMapScriptURL + CurrentKey + "&callback=MyGMap.InitializeMaps");
```

Comment: Just to add on, [Dion Almaer mentions the use of the `callback` on his blog](http://almaer.com/blog/dynamically-loading-google-maps-for-performance)
(I was typing out my answer when this answer appeared first so I scrapped mine.)

Comment: strange...now i get an error: _mF is not defined
where is this coming from?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I typoed `Initiazlize` - I didn't spot you had a z in the middle. Maybe that's it? :-/

Comment: yeah, thanks, now i see the Google Logo at least..
but no Map...
you know why?

Comment: No, sorry - that all looks OK to me now. I'd have guessed zoom level but 13 works fine at http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?q=37.4419,+-122.1419&z=13

Comment: Ok, got it: forgot to give the map_canvas div  height/width ;)
thx!

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the async mode, but you need to provide a callback function.

Here http://lucamanzo-soluzione-software.it/wp/?p=5 you can find a simple jquery plugin showing all the steps to use the async loading and jquery, and building a map with just a few lines of code:

```
$.gmapstools.init();
$("#my_map_canvas").gmap({lat:37.4221913, lng:-122.08458530000001, draw_marker:true, zoom_level:13});
```