# how to load a div from an external html page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an html page with google maps in one of the divs called map.

```
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),mapOptions);
```

Now I want to have the same google maps in multiple webpages. How do I reference this div in other pages.

For e.g.

I have another html file like this

```
<html><head></head>
<body><div><!--How do I get the map here--></div>
</body></html>
```

Is it posible using Jquery?

---edit----

So I have a script called myscript.js
which has a

`jQuery(document).ready(function(){`

which in turn has a

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),mapOptions);
```

So how do I load this script anywhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't reference this div. Map is generated on the fly when page is loaded.

If you thought about using `$('#element').load('map.html #map)` - it will stripe all the scripts from loaded content, so generation scripts won't be available to run.

Since it's supposed to be the same map try use jQuery.getScript()?

```
// gmaps.js
function generateMap() {
   //your custom logic
}

// html file
<html><head></head>
<body><div id="gmap"></div>
<script>
$.getScript('gmaps.js', function() {
    // Call custom function defined in script
    generateMap();
});

</script>
</body></html>
```

You might also look at examples here on stackoverflow of using `jQuery.getScript()` and google maps:

- [jquery: how can i load the Google Maps API via ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811787/jquery-how-can-i-load-the-google-maps-api-via-ajax)
- [jQuery getScript and Google Maps API Error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965898/jquery-getscript-and-google-maps-api-problem)
- http://lostmonocle.com/post/88217865/jquery-getscript-and-the-google-maps-api

**EDIT** - updated example

```
// map.js
function generateMap()
{
    map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("div_map"));
    map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
    map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
    var latLong = new GLatLng(parseFloat(52.2322549), parseFloat(21.0387957));
    var marker = new GMarker(latLong, {draggable : false});
    map.addOverlay(marker);
    map.setCenter(latLong, 15);
}


// map.html - ! CHANGE API KEY !
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Google Map sample</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1-min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=PUT_YOUR_KEY_HERE&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
<body>
<div id="div_map" style="width:500px;height:400px;background-color:red;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.getScript('map.js', function() {
    generateMap();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How does your full javascript file look like? Put there only function for map generation. I've updated example

Answer (score 0):

Presuming that you're not looking to actually duplicate the map instance itself on other pages, I would suggest creating a standalone page that you can then reference via an `<iframe>`.  You could try via jQuery, but the map will likely break.